# Where should I unserialize it? php/wordpress creating my own plugin

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I've serialized data from checkbox, from form:

```
$obj_box = serialize($_POST['obj_box']);
```

Send it to table in mysql:

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "fl_insert_floor";
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
obj_box` text NOT NULL,
)

$wpdb->insert( 
$table,array( 
'obj_box' => $obj_box
));
```

I am browsing the data, and want to display unserialize data:

```
function flif_browsing() {
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "fl_insert_floor";

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_fl_insert_floor`") or die('Error3');

 echo '<table summary="Properties" id="table1">';
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td><b>Typ obiektu</b></td>';
 echo '</tr>';

foreach ($result as $result1) {

 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'.$get_object_id = $result1->obj_box.'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 echo '</br>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
 }
```

Where should I unserialize it? (trying different methods and getting errors).
Or there is a better method to send it from checkbox to table in mysql and later display it?

Comment: Did not resolve problem, but made alternative solution: each checkbox is made seprately, put into database as separate record and displayed, if is true.